# Adding RAID after Installation of Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, raid

I have an HP Proliant Server 100ML G6 with with Windows Server 2008. Installed. I first installed the
system with out enabling the onboard raid controller. So, now windows is install on the first hard drive.

I wanted to activate the raid, so I went into the BIOS and change the HD Controller from "Compatible"
to "RAID". Then I configured RAID 01 automatically, and went on to boot.

Now windows started, and after 10 seconds crashes with BSOD, but I can't read the error message. It lasts only 1 Sec.

Setting the HD Controller in the BIOS back to "Compatible" will allow me to start windows server normally.

So, my question is, how do I make windows boot with this RAID option, with out Reinstalling the OS...

EDIT:

Well, there are 2 HDs. 
Windows is installed in C: ofcourse, 
and the other HD has no partition table on it.

Comment: Could you specify the number of drives and on which drive the OS is installed and which drives are part of raid. From what it sounds like you initialised your OS drive part of hardware raid and "wiped" the OS.

Comment: What is wierd, is that windows boots... so I need to change from 01 to raid 10 or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to install the RAID drivers on windows before you change the option to RAID.  Depending on the drivers they may refuse to install without the hardware detected so if that is a problem you will need to google the trick to force it for your specific raid card.

Comment: I'll try that, but I will have access to the server only in about 6 hours again. I'll post here an answer if it works.